# How to keep hdf5 binary of a pandas dataframe in-memory?

Tags: python, pandas, hdf5, pytables, python-3.9

I would like to get the byte contents of a pandas dataframe exported as hdf5, ideally without actually saving the file (i.e., in-memory).

On `python>=3.6, < 3.9` (and `pandas==1.2.4`, `pytables==3.6.1`) the following used to work:

```py
import pandas as pd
with pd.HDFStore(
    "in-memory-save-file",
    mode="w",
    driver="H5FD_CORE",
    driver_core_backing_store=0,
) as store:
    store.put("my_key", df, format="table")
    binary_data = store._handle.get_file_image()
```

Where `df` is the dataframe to be converted to hdf5, and the last line calls [this `pytables` function](https://github.com/PyTables/PyTables/blob/master/tables/hdf5extension.pyx#L498).

However, starting with python 3.9, I get the following error when using the snippet above:

```
File "tables/hdf5extension.pyx", line 523, in tables.hdf5extension.File.get_file_image
tables.exceptions.HDF5ExtError: Unable to retrieve the size of the buffer for the file image.  Plese note that not all drivers provide support for image files.
```

The error is raised by the same `pytables` function linked above, apparently due to issues while *[retrieving the size of the buffer for the file image](https://github.com/PyTables/PyTables/blob/master/tables/hdf5extension.pyx#L516)*. I don't understand the ultimate reason for it, though.

I have tried other alternatives such as saving to a [`BytesIO` file-object](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html), so far unsuccessfully.

How can I keep the hdf5 binary of a pandas dataframe in-memory on python 3.9?

Comment: [This](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/9246) is a related (albeit old) discussion on github where the call to `get_file_image()` is suggested

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fix was to do `conda install -c conda-forge pytables` instead of `pip install pytables`. I still don't understand the ultimate reason behind the error, though.